# Set service status into Stop_Pending

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a **powershell** script to check if service status is in stop pending state or start pending state.

- How do I change the service status into `Stop_Pending` status for a testing purpose? It helps me to check my script is working or not.
- Is there any tool to test this like stress test for CPU and memory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got Visual Studio - would take 15 minutes to get this set up:

http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html

change line 10 to have a sleep statement in it. That's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not scared to mess a little bit your system try this:

> Get-Service | ForEach-Object { Set-Service $_.Name -Status Paused }

A lot of people are asking same question that it's required for testing purpose but no one gave good answer.